# Jquery check input trim

Tags: javascript, jquery, trim, texttrimming

How can i create a custom function in jquery?

I want to use that on text inputs, to check with trim, that the user really entered some text, or just white spaces.

Comment: use Jquery function  $.trim on the value of the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .trim() function.

```
if ($.trim($("input-selector").val()))
{
   //do Something
}
```

Comment: He can check directly $.trim($("input-selector").val());

Comment: You mean like this?

kerdes_nev = $('#kerdes_nev').val();

if (!$.trim(kerdes_nev)) { FormErros.push("Show the error message...."); }

Comment: @Takács Zoltán: Yes,It depends on your validation and show error message mechanism.and you can also using jquery validation plugin: https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/